# How to do if-else in regex based on previous regex in the pattern (Python)?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match urls of the form

`r'https://.*\.mysite.com'`

However, one will notice that if there is no subdomain `.mysite.com` isn't going to be valid. If there is a subdomain such as `sub.mysite.com`, only then do I want a dot in front of mysite, otherwise, I want 0 dots (or more generally, characters) between `https://` and `mysite.com`

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: This: `r'https://.*?\.?mysite.com'` ?

Comment: no it would recognize <letters>?mysite.com'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be a Python-specific problem but more of a RegEx one.

You could modify your expression to optionally accept a subdomain as such:

```
https:\/\/([^.]+\.)?mysite\.com
```

Or allow for multi-level subdomains:

```
https:\/\/([^.]+\.)*mysite\.com
```

Additionally, if you didn't want to use a capture group, you could use a non-capturing group:

```
https:\/\/(?:[^.]+\.)*mysite\.com
```

Comment: https://(?:.+\.)? mysite.com, again dont do .*

Comment: @user8426627 good catch, edited

Comment: @andrewgu why would i want capturing vs non-capturing?

Comment: Also the problem with this is `https:..mysite.com` passes

Comment: @AlanH I've updated my answer to account for that possibility. You really only care about capture groups when you need to use part of the matching pattern.